# Лишний автоинкремент в таблице

Tags: c#, sql-server

Создал таблицу в конструкторе MS SQL Server. 
Связал с DataGridView, настроил автоинкремент поля ID. Теперь, по неведомой мне причине пустая строка (следующая за последней заполненной) инкрементирует  ID каждый раз, когда я нажимаю на название любого столбца. Что это может быть?

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Clients] (
    [Client_ID]  INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [CName]      INT            NOT NULL,
    [Phone]      NUMERIC (18)   NOT NULL,
    [Email]      NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [Birthday]   DATE           NOT NULL,
    [Last_Visit] DATETIME       NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Client_ID] ASC)
);
```

Comment: Инкрементируется ID в какой строке?

Comment: Что означает фраза "настроил автоинкремент поля ID"?

Comment: @DenisRubashkin по неведомой причине хотя я и пишу IDENTITY(1, 1) что означает каждой записи присваивать ID начиная с 1 инкрементируя на 1, почему-то в DataSet AutoIncrementSeed и Step ставились на -1, в следствие чего IDшники были отрицательными (и все равно происходила описанная проблема)

Comment: @4per в пустой строке, следующей за последней заполненной

Comment: IDENTITY поле таблицы и свойства DataSet-а это две большие разницы, на клиентской стороне вообще ничего не нужно делать  с полем Client_ID кроме чтения, потому что ни добавить, ни изменить его не получится.

Comment: @AlexSherzhukov, счетчик срабатывает значит. Это не должно вас беспокоить.

Comment: @DenisRubashkin так и есть, поле рид-онли